# I inadvertently locked my HTC 1 via "find my phone" (wrong phone). I "found" it but cannot access it.

Tags: security

I use this phone for my TV. Earlier I had mislaid my regular phone and in a bit of a panic, I thought I locked it via "Find my phone", but actually locked the HTC 1.  I now have both phones in my hot little hand, but cannot access the HTC 1 due to the lock.  I can find no entry point for the password -- or anything else --.  Can anyone help?
Richard Archer

Answer (score 0):

This should be the screen you should see on your phone when you remotely lock it using Google's '[find my device](https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?service=androidconsole&passive=1209600&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fandroid%2Ffind&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fandroid%2Ffind&ltmpl=findmydevice&rart=ANgoxcfd-o61mty7x1B7x237fAn6eY_pu_FmH8KQiKF4PLHhuFJoBG78ir_oL3aDvAlllrmWfznw26U6_qL35oujQeQzEvR_iQ&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin)' [image]

Simply drag the lock icon in any direction and that will direct you to a page where you can enter the code that you have set when remotely locking the device. On newer devices, it will ask you to enter the regular code that you use when unlocking your phone.

If the above is not what you see on your screen, then restarting your phone should bring it up.